# Elasticsearch Percentile Aggregation on two fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-aggregation

I would like to retrieve the Q1 and Q2 from a set of values that is distributed in two fields.

My documents look like:

```
{
   amount: 100,
   type: "CREDIT"
}
{
   amount: 80,
   type: "DEBIT"
}
```

Those amounts represent actually values of 100 and -80 respectively.

Let's say my all the values of my collection are `[100, -80, 20, -30, 50]`, so my percentiles would be `Q1=-30` and `Q3=-50`.

How can I write a query that tells elasticsearhc that documents with *type: "DEBIT"* need to be taken into account as negative values and then performe the percentile aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script to perform percentile aggregation. Below script checks if type is debit then return negative value else return positive value

```
"aggs": {
    "percentile_val": {
      "percentiles": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "if( doc['type.keyword'].value=='DEBIT') { return -doc['amount'].value;} else {doc['amount'].value}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Glad could be of help.

Comment: What if the percentile aggregation need to be performed on the results of a query (But don't want to get the query result to be sent, just need the percentiles)?
```{
   "aggs": { ... }
  },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "name":"Paco Jones"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}```
This returns all the docs content in hits

Comment: you can make size:0 in query part